# Something similar to $1 but gathers all input regardless of whitespace

Tags: unix, variables, command-line, terminal

Is there something similar to $1, but that gathers all input from the terminal input, including whitespace characters?  This would be used to collect a pasted directory path that may have whitespaces - I need the whole string.

Thanks In Advance

Thankfully, I've received the answer to my first question. In execution, however, I can't get it to work.  Here is my code.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
alias finder='cd $* && open .'
```

It's returning segmented returns - every time it hits a space, it treats it as a separate entry.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`$*` or `$@`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF).

> `$*` All of the positional parameters, seen as a single word
>
> `$@` Same as `$*`, but each parameter is a quoted string, that is, the
>   parameters are passed on intact, without interpretation or expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd just refer to the first argument as `"$1"`, including the quotation marks.  If you want to use a directory name as an argument, and the name has spaces in it, you'd typically quote it on the command line:

```
alias finder='cd "$1" && open .'

...

finder "/some/dir/with spaces/in its name"
```

That also works well with tab completion, which escapes whitespace for you.  And in this particular case, you probably might as well use the `open` command directly.

But if you want the `finder` alias to concatenate multiple arguments into a single string, separated by spaces, that actually turns out to be harder.  I've tried some possibilities using `$*` and `$@`, but they don't work correctly.  For testing, I'm using my own command `echol`, which prints each of its arguments on a separate line.

```
$ echol foo bar
foo
bar
$ alias e='echol "$*"'
$ e foo bar

foo
bar
$ alias e='eval echo \""$*"\"'
$ e foo bar
 foo bar
```

That last one is the closest I've come, but it adds an extra leading space.

I think you're better off just quoting the directory name.

Comment: That's what I'll do then.  Thanks for your reply.